Stamp in pdf draggable in html?
I need to create a stamp to mark a signature area, I need to add an HTML element that shows me the x and y position, and the element can be dragged between pages, has anyone already implemented this solution?

I tried using the ngx-extended-pdf-viewer component, I couldn't render HTML or get the position of the element

public async addTextEditorForPage(pageNumber: number): Promise<void> {
    const pageSize = await this.getPageSize(pageNumber);
    console.log(`Page ${pageNumber} - Orientation: ${pageSize.orientation}`);

    const lines = await this.pdfService.getPageAsLines(pageNumber);
    const firstLineHeight = lines.length > 0 ? lines[0].height : 0;

    const rectWidth = pageSize.orientation === 'landscape' ? lines[lines.length - 1].width - 20 : firstLineHeight;

    const textEditorAnnotation: FreeTextEditorAnnotation = {
      annotationType: 3,
      color: [0, 0, 0],
      fontSize: 13,
      value: `ABCABCABC TEST`,
      pageIndex: pageNumber - 1, // Índices de página começam do 0
      rect: [
        100, // espaço entre a borda da esquerda e o texto
        0,
        0,
        rectWidth,
      ],
      rotation: 0,
    };


    this.addedAnnotations.push(textEditorAnnotation);
    this.pdfService.addEditorAnnotation(textEditorAnnotation);

  }


I managed to do it using the StampAnnotations.
First create a stamp annotation using the PDFViewerService
service.addImageToAnnotationLayer(...)
And then, after it is added I apply some transformations to it, like adding some custom text.
Although this might not be the intended purpose of the StampAnnotations it allows you to drag-and-drop and also it wont have the "text edit" when you click on it.
To get the positions, just use
service.getSerializedAnnotations()
It would be handy if you could extend these annotations to your liking in a better way
